# Encapsulating properties of inherited objects with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, scope

I'm writing an API in node.js (and I'm a n00b with js).  I have a parent resource method which I'd like to extend for each specific resource to DRY up my code.  Here's what I have

resource.js:

```
function Resource(model) {
   this.Model = model;
};


Resource.prototype.getAll = function(req, res) {
   this.Model.find(req.query).exec(function(err, all) {
      ...
   };
};

module.exports = Resource;
```

user.js:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
   inherits = require('util').inherits,
   Model = require('./resource.js'),
   UserModel = mongoose.model('User');;

function User() {
   Model.call(this, UserModel);
};

inherits(User, Model);

module.exports = new User();
```

artist.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
   inherits = require('util').inherits,
   Model = require('./resource.js'),
   ArtistModel = mongoose.model('Artist');

function Artist() {
   Model.call(this, ArtistModel);
};

inherits(Artist, Model);

module.exports = new Artist();
```

Then in my route I do:

```
var UserResource = require('./user2.js'),
   ArtistResource = require('./artist2.js');

app.get('/api/user', UserResource.getAll);
```

When I try to hit /api/user I get an undefined error when it tries to call `this.Model.find()`.

I also tried setting a global Model var in resource.js, but then that gets overriden when it calls `require('./artist2.js')`

How do I go about getting encapsulation similar to more OO languages... or even better, what is the recommended way of doing this in JavaScript?  I want to be able to extend functions in the children by doing some pre-processing then calling the parent function.

Comment: Why is `Model` a global variable rather than an instance variable?  It sounds like you need some basic reading on inheritance in javascript.  Here are a couple references [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and [here](https://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance/) and [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/).

Comment: @jfriend00 As I mentioned at the end... I also tried using an instance variable.  I tried that first but it didn't work, and I tried this afterward (and thus is what got copied in here) I'll update it to reflect my original code which is what, to me, seemed correct.

Comment: Where is the code that actually creates a `Resource` object and the calls `getAll()` on it?  If `this.Model.find()` doesn't work, it's probably because `this` is not set correctly which is probably because you aren't called `getAll()` correctly.

Comment: @jfriend00 The code that extends the Resource object is in both user.js and artist.js.  Each one extends it and instanciates the new object using their respective mongoose model.  The function getAll then gets assigned as the callback for an express route in route.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is probably when you pass a method like this as a callback:

```
app.get('/api/user', UserResource.getAll);
```

This ends up passing a reference to the method, but then the method gets called with no object reference and thus the `this` pointer is not set appropriately.

It's kind of like this:

```
var f = UserResource.getAll;
f();
```

This ends up calling `getAll()` without any object reference so the `this` pointer is NOT set to that object.

There are a couple ways around this, but the simplest is probably to use `.bind()` like this:

```
app.get('/api/user', UserResource.getAll.bind(UserResource));
```

This will create a small function stub that will then actually call `UserResource.getAll()` rather than just call `getAll()` and will keep the method bound to the appropriate object through the callback and thus set the `this` pointer appropriately.

This must be done anytime you're passing a method as a callback and need it to get called in the context of the appropriate object (which is nearly always the case with methods).

Comment: It's a little messier than I would like, but it works! thanks